# DirectX Issue with .Net Framework 4.0 Application

Tags: .net, directx

I'm working on a Windows 7 (64bit) machine with DirectX version 11. I'm getting an error `"Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack"` and application hangs when I'm trying to check the availability of `DirectX` in the machine. Below is the method I'm using to check `DirectX`:

```
private bool CheckForDirectX()
{
    try
    {
        bool res = false;

        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Direct3D\Drivers");

        if (key == null)
            return false;

        res = true;
        res = Convert.ToInt32(key.GetValue("SoftwareOnly")) == 0;

        if (!res)
            return res;

        bool m_windowed = false;
        int softOnly = Convert.ToInt32(key.GetValue("SoftwareOnly"));

        DisplayMode m_displayMode = Manager.Adapters != null && Manager.Adapters.Count > 0 ? Manager.Adapters[0].CurrentDisplayMode : new DisplayMode();
        Format adaptorFormat = (m_windowed) ? m_displayMode.Format : Format.X8R8G8B8;

        if (Manager.CheckDeviceFormat(0, DeviceType.Hardware, adaptorFormat, Usage.DepthStencil, Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.ResourceType.Surface, DepthFormat.D24S8))
            res = true;
        else if (Manager.CheckDeviceFormat(0, DeviceType.Hardware, adaptorFormat, Usage.DepthStencil, Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.ResourceType.Surface, DepthFormat.D24X8))
            res = true;
        else if (Manager.CheckDeviceFormat(0, DeviceType.Hardware, adaptorFormat, Usage.DepthStencil, Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.ResourceType.Surface, DepthFormat.D16))
            res = true;
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DirectX device format problem");
            return false;
        }

        if (softOnly == 0 && res)
            return true;
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DirectX is not enabled");
            return false;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("CheckDirectXEnabled returned false");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Application hangs at the place I'm calling this method.

Comment: It appears you are using the [legacy Managed DirectX 1.1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx) assemblies here. You should consider using something newer like [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) or [SlimDX](http://www.slimdx.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here. It's not an issue with DirectX or .NET framework. This issue caused because DirectX assemblies were compiled under different runtime environment, and the way CLR 4.0 loads mixed mode assemblies changed. 
So as the solution we need to add the following entry, to your app.config file. This will allow the CLR 4.0 runtime to use lagacy assembly loading.

```
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup>
```

Good luck with your coding! :)